# java.lang.nullpointer exception thrown in servlet program

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, myeclipse

I am creating a 3-tier web application for an online exam having just 5 questions.I use html and have designed a servlet to post data to the mysql database which I have named as 'test' and the table is 'st1'. I use MyEclipse Blue 8.6.1 which has an inbuilt MyEclipse Tomcat 6.0.13. The coding for servlet in doPost() method is as follows:

```
try
{
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
    message="Connection Sucessfull";
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
    cnfex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(SQLException sqlex){
    sqlex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception excp){
    excp.printStackTrace();
}
seat_no=request.getParameter("Seat_No");
name=request.getParameter("Name");
ans1=request.getParameter("group1");
ans2=request.getParameter("group2");
ans3=request.getParameter("group3");
ans4=request.getParameter("group4");
ans5=request.getParameter("group5");
if(ans1.equals("True"))
    Total+=2;
if(ans2.equals("False"))
    Total+=2;
if(ans3.equals("True"))
    Total+=2;
if(ans4.equals("False"))
    Total+=2;
if(ans5.equals("False"))
    Total+=2;
try
{
    Statement stmt=connect.createStatement();
    String query="INSERT INTO st1("+"seat_no,name,marks"+")VALUES('"+seat_no+"','"+name+"','"+Total+"')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    stmt.close();
}
```

When I compile the application, I keep getting an exception as such:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

type Exception report
message: 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception :
java.lang.NullPointerException
    s3.doPost(s3.java:52)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
note :The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.13 logs
```

---

But I could not find any logs available for MyEclipse Tomcat 6.0.13. Can anyone help me overcome this exception? Its my academic project ! Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the file s3.java, line 52.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that one of the fields you are retrieving via `getParameter` is not there so it in `null`. Whend you call `.equals()` on that field you get NPE. If we know which line is #52 it would help.

As a first step I would rewrite all the checks which are like:

```
ans1.equals("True")
```

to

```
"true".equalsIgnoreCase(ans1)
```

or even better

```
Boolean.getBoolean(ans1) == true
```

Then you will not get NPE even if the field was not presented in the request.

Answer (score 1):

supporting answer from @Jan Zyka

Try this

```
if("True".equals(ans1))
    Total+=2;
if("False".equals(ans2))
    Total+=2;
if("True".equals(ans3))
    Total+=2;
if("False".equals(ans4))
    Total+=2;
if("False".equals(ans5))
    Total+=2;
try
{
   if(Total>0)// Just a condition.. !
   {
    Statement stmt=connect.createStatement();
    String query="INSERT INTO st1("+"seat_no,name,marks"+")VALUES('"+seat_no+"','"+name+"','"+Total+"')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    stmt.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be ending with any parameter with `NULL` at file s3.java, line 52

Check what parameters are you getting there ?